# What do we call "A person who disowns during bad times and claims during good times"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there any single word to describe a mentality of a person who disowns something during bad times and claims the same during good times?

Comment: "Fairweather friend", certainly in interpersonal relations. But can you specify what the "something" is in this case? It might warrant a more precise idea.

Comment: something can be a Team (Football team)

Comment: added an answer, but in this case I would definitely use "fairweather fan" which is a nice fit for exactly the case you mention (football team).

Comment: Maybe an *investor* ;)

Comment: That would be a "politician".

Answer (score 3):

**"Fairweather fan"** does the trick in the case of a sports team.

> A person who is supportive of and enthusiastic about a sports team only when that team is performing well.
>
> *"I've been rooting for the home team in their playoff run, but I'll admit I'm just a fair-weather fan."*

[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fairweather+fan)

Comment: It [would actually be hyphenated](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fairweather+fan%2Cfair-weather+fan%2Cfair-weather+friend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfair%20-%20weather%20fan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfair%20-%20weather%20friend%3B%2Cc0), but ***fair-weather fan*** is virtually unknown by comparison with ***fair-weather friend***.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it a [[help] vampire](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=help%20vampire). From Urban Dictionary:

> A term used most frequently by chat room programmers for blood suckers who aren't interested in the functions or inner workings of a solution but rather the end result. They normally mask themselves in chat rooms pretending to ask for "help."

---

See also: [The help vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) and [slash7](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).